# Is it better to use AVD or USB debugging to test Android App?

Tags: android, performance, ubuntu-14.04, android-virtual-device

I'm building an android app on Ubuntu, though the AVD freezes the machine or sometimes breaks before running the app. I have i5 5th gen, 4GB ram.
Could it be less costly (computation-wise) to use the USB degugger?

Thanks

Comment: What is USB Debugger? Is it some tool to test Android app on?

Comment: @AADTechnical   "USB debugger" in this context is simply connecting your android device to your machine and using it to preview/debug your app instead of using the Android Virtual Device (AVD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to increase RAM. There are so many files that need to be in memory for smooth debugging. In your case, it must be freezing because of continuous swapping of files from RAM to HDD and vice versa. So try putting another 8GB chip.

Currently debugging on emulator is slower than device in my case. Emulators [will be faster](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/11/android-studio-20-preview.html?m=1) in Android Studio 2.0 release.

Comment: Thanks Mangesh, the avd works whenever I use an older API between 1 and 19